# ¿En NLTK cómo evito que filtrar las palabras con lower() y con el método stopwords() desencadene el error: 'list' object has no attribute 'words'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp

esta es mi primera publicación. Soy un novato en python3 / NLTK y también soy nuevo en Ciencias de la computación, pero hasta ahora he logrado resolver todos los problemas, sin embargo, necesito desesperadamente su apoyo con esto.
Lo que estoy haciendo es analizar dos corpus (discursos políticos) utilizando la distribución de frecuencia condicional.
**Lo que quiero lograr es**:

- Convertir toda la cadena a minúsculas para que no tenga duplicados.
- Poder incluir excepciones dentro del método más bajo (), de modo que pueda evitar que palabras tales como general (adjetivo) y General (el Sustantivo, como en General del ejército) se mezclen.
- También quiero utilizar el método stopwords () para deshacerme de todas las palabras de relleno (con algunas excepciones).

**Mi problema**
Después de intentar filtrar los textos usando estos criterios, termino con una lista que me da el siguiente error de atributo:

```
for word in content_filtered.words(categories=category)]
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'words'
```

**Nota:** el programa funciona bien si uso

```
reader.words (categorías = categoría)]
```

¡pero no filtra nada!
**Mi código**

```
import re
from  nltk import *
from nltk.corpus import PlaintextCorpusReader
from nltk.corpus.reader import CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.text import Text
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop_words= set(stopwords.words("spanish"))

corpus_root= r"C:\Users\rexfarell\Desktop\LatinamericanTextResources-master\corpora"

reader=CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader(corpus_root,r"speeches_.*\.xml",cat_pattern=r"speeches_(\w+)\.xml")
print(reader.fileids())
texts=reader.words()
textlist=(Text(texts))    
textlist.concordance("comunismo")

words_filtered=stopwords.words("spanish")
content_filtered=[w for w in textlist if w.lower() not in words_filtered]         
content_filtered=(set(content_filtered))

category_word = [(category, word)
for category in ["Uribismos","Santismos"]
for word in content_filtered.words(categories=category)]

print(category_word[:15])
print(category_word[-15: ])
```